# AngularJS - redirect to another page

Tags: angularjs, redirect

I learn AngularJS and I have a problem with redirecting page.

Usecase:

- I have a index.html homepage but if the user is not logged in then it should redirect to the login.html page (also each page should be accessible only to logged-in user)

in the main app.js I have a provider and runner :

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "ngAnimate", "ngResource"]);

app.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            template: "index.html"
        })
        .when("/other", {
            templateUrl: "other.html"
        });
}]);


app.run(["$rootScope", "LoginService", function($rootScope, LoginService, $window) {
    LoginService.checkSession().then(function(response) {
        $rootScope.isLoggedIn = response;
            if ($rootScope.isLoggedIn === false) {
                console.log('DENY');
                $window.location.href = '/login';
            }
    }, function(reject) {
        $rootScope.isLoggedIn = reject;
    });
}]);
```

the problem: 
when I'm not logged in it when it comes to the line "$window.location.href ='/login'" This is an error in the console:

```
DENY 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
    at LoginService.checkSession.then.$rootScope.isLoggedIn
```

when I set the debugger before the line, it prints:

```
$window
undefined
```

I do not know why this is happening. Could someone help me solve this problem?

best regards, 
Luke

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to inject `$window` as a string in the "injection array":

```
["$rootScope", "LoginService","$window", function($rootScope, LoginService, $window)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define app.run, you're not passing in $window for the Dependency Injection.

```
   app.run(["$rootScope", "LoginService", function($rootScope, LoginService, $window)
```

Try replacing the above line with this

```
app.run(["$rootScope", "LoginService","$window", function($rootScope, LoginService, $window)
```